# Exporting combined data plots as a PDF file

Tags: plotting, export

I am trying to export a graph similar to the one attached as PDF.
I am having troubles with the error bars and legends.

[image]

Is there a simple example someone can share and demonstrate how to do this?

Comment: What trouble are you having? Did you use the Export command? What did you type? What error did you get? For additional information http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ExportToPDF.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/PDF.html

Comment: Please add data to reproduce the plot and code/details to show us what your problem is.

Comment: Looking at the picture I'd say the problem is that some error bars are (partly) dropped. The one on the bottom of the plot exhibits an artifact. The problem with the legend is not readily apparent.I'm not sure about the color of the error bars. They should be in the color of the individual lines.

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me (Mathematica 9.0.1, Win7-64):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

pl = 
ErrorListPlot[
  Table[{j Sqrt[i], Max[0.2, RandomReal[1]]}, {j, 1, 4}, {i, 10}], 
  Joined -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"One fish", "Two fish", "Red fish", "Blue fish"}, 
                     LegendFunction -> Frame, 
                     Background -> White
          ], 
          {Scaled[{0.03, 0.75}], {0, 0.5}}
   ], 
  Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{20, 10}, {20, 10}}
]
```

[image]

Exporting:

```
Export["C:\\yourPath\\plot.pdf", pl]
```

And here a screendump of the PDF as seen in Adobe Acrobat:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot this is great. What about the X axis?

Comment: @Doron. You're speaking in riddles. What's wrong with the x-axis?

Comment: Sjored C. de Vries: you are right. Please excuse me it is all OK.